# Time offset of "Recognized Phrase" in Microsoft.Speech.Recognition

Tags: .net, speech-recognition

Using Microsoft's Speech API I'd like to have it recognize a specific phrase then return to me the time in which the phrase was detected in the audio.

For example:

**phrase**: "I like apples"

**audio**: 5 minutes of audio

Say at 3m30s the phrase is detected, I'd like to store that information along with the fact the phrase exists in the audio. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an example that uses "AudioPosition", seems to be what I'm looking for:

**Source:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.speech.recognition.speechrecognizedeventargs(v=office.14).aspx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Speech.Recognition;

namespace SampleRecognition
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)

    // Initialize a SpeechRecognitionEngine object.
    {
      using (SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = 
        new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")))
      {

        // Create SemanticResultValue objects that contain cities and airport codes.
        SemanticResultValue chicago = new SemanticResultValue("Chicago", "ORD");
        SemanticResultValue boston = new SemanticResultValue("Boston", "BOS");
        SemanticResultValue miami = new SemanticResultValue("Miami", "MIA");
        SemanticResultValue dallas = new SemanticResultValue("Dallas", "DFW");

        // Create a Choices object and add the SemanticResultValue objects.
        Choices cities = new Choices();
        cities.Add(new Choices(new GrammarBuilder[] { chicago, boston, miami, dallas }));

        // Build the phrase and add SemanticResultKeys.
        GrammarBuilder chooseCities = new GrammarBuilder();
        chooseCities.Append("I want to fly from");
        chooseCities.Append(new SemanticResultKey("origin", cities));
        chooseCities.Append("to");
        chooseCities.Append(new SemanticResultKey("destination", cities));

        // Build a Grammar object from the GrammarBuilder.
        Grammar bookFlight = new Grammar(chooseCities);
        bookFlight.Name = "Book Flight";

        // Add a handler for the SpeechRecognized event.
        recognizer.SpeechRecognized +=
          new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recognizer_SpeechRecognized);

        // Load the grammar object to the recognizer.
        recognizer.LoadGrammarAsync(bookFlight);

        // Set the input to the recognizer.
        recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        // Start recognition.
        recognizer.RecognizeAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Starting asynchronous recognition...");

        // Keep the console window open.
        Console.ReadLine();
      }
    }

    // Handle the SpeechRecognized event.
    static void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Recognition result summary:");
      Console.WriteLine(
        "  Recognized phrase: {0}\n" +
        "  Confidence score {1}\n" +
        "  Grammar used: {2}\n",
        e.Result.Text, e.Result.Confidence, e.Result.Grammar.Name);

      // Display the semantic values in the recognition result.
      Console.WriteLine("  Semantic results:");
      foreach (KeyValuePair<String, SemanticValue> child in e.Result.Semantics)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("    The {0} city is {1}",
          child.Key, child.Value.Value ?? "null");
      }
      Console.WriteLine();

      // Display information about the words in the recognition result.
      Console.WriteLine("  Word summary: ");
      foreach (RecognizedWordUnit word in e.Result.Words)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(
          "    Lexical form ({1})" +
          " Pronunciation ({0})" +
          " Display form ({2})",
          word.Pronunciation, word.LexicalForm, word.DisplayAttributes);
      }

      // Display information about the audio in the recognition result.
      Console.WriteLine("  Input audio summary:\n" +
            "    Candidate Phrase at:       {0} mSec\n" +
            "    Phrase Length:             {1} mSec\n" +
            "    Input State Time:          {2}\n" +
            "    Input Format:              {3}\n",
            e.Result.Audio.AudioPosition,
            e.Result.Audio.Duration,
            e.Result.Audio.StartTime,
            e.Result.Audio.Format.EncodingFormat);

      // Display information about the alternate recognitions in the recognition result.
      Console.WriteLine("  Alternate phrase collection:");
      foreach (RecognizedPhrase phrase in e.Result.Alternates)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("    Phrase: " + phrase.Text);
        Console.WriteLine("    Confidence score: " + phrase.Confidence);
      }

      // Display information about text that was replaced during normalization.
      if (e.Result.ReplacementWordUnits.Count != 0)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("  Replacement text:\n");
        foreach (ReplacementText rep in e.Result.ReplacementWordUnits)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("      At index {0} for {1} words. Text: {2}\n",
          rep.FirstWordIndex, rep.CountOfWords, rep.Text);
        }
        //label.Text += String.Format("\n\n");

      }
      else
      {
        Console.WriteLine(); 
        Console.WriteLine("No text was replaced");
      }
    }
  }
}
```